# why is fgets() function not prompting user for input the second time?

Tags: c, string, input, fgets

The code is:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>

        int main (void)
        {
            char ch,str[100],sen[100];
            printf("enter the string : ");
            fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
            printf("enter the character : ");
            scanf("%c",&ch);
            printf("enter  the sentence : ");
            fgets(sen,sizeof(sen),stdin);
            printf("character is : %c\n",ch);
            printf("string is : %s\n",str);
            printf("sentence is : %s",sen);
            return 0;
        }
```

this is how i expect my programm to work:
input:

```
    enter the string : abcde
    enter the character : k
    enter the sentence : i am a beginner.
```

output:

```
    character is : k
    string is : abcde
    sentence is : i am a beginner.
```

this is what it results in :

```
    enter the string : abcde
    enter the character : k
    enter  the sentence : character is : k
    string is : abcde
    
    sentence is :
```

This program is not prompting the user to input sentence.
Please tell me why this `fgets()` function is not working properly.

Comment: `fgets()` is only for reading things. Therefore it won't prompt things.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&ch);` reads only one character. It leaves newline character in the buffer if it is entered and the newline character will consumed by following `fgets()`.

Comment: Call getchar() after your scanf to consume the newline character left in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` is working just fine.  You do not flush stdout, so the printf writes data to an internal buffer but does not produce any actual output before `fgets` blocks on a read.  Just add `fflush(stdout)` after the printfs.